# Intl.NumberFormat different output in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I am trying to use Intl.NumberFormat along with browser locale to get currency information.

```
var amount = 654321.987;

    var options1 = { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR', currencyDisplay:'name' };
    var numberFormat1 = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', options1);

    console.log(numberFormat1.format(amount));
```

Using the above code gives me different output in IE11 and chrome. Why is different across browser and how we have a standard output.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is inconsistent on different browsers, there's no easy way around this, you can implement your own formatting function. If you try using just the symbol instead of currency name then it'll look the same.

```js
var number = 123456.789;
var opts =  { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'};
    
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', opts).format(number));
```

You can also wrap the function above and then append the symbol yourself to keep it consistent across browsers :)

Comment: I was looking at the Currency Formatter NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/currency-formatter but it is mentioned to use the  JavaScript Internationalization API. So might have to go back to this